# How to do random select from two tables with the exception?

Tags: mysql, select, random

I have two tables

**[users]**
id, username, age, sity .... and other

and

**[teacherlook]**
id, userid, teachid, data

When teacher look user from first table [users], he insert value to the second table

> NULL, userid (it is id value from first table), teacherid (it is unic
>   id of teacher - can may be 1,2,3 ... 10), and time in unix

It's done, it works,

Problem with second part of script:

The teacher should see 10 random users whom he has not yet tested - those who are not yet in the second table.

I try

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users 
  JOIN teacherlook 
 WHERE users.age>18 
   AND (users.id<>teacherlook.userid AND teacherlook.teachid<>$teacherid)     
 LIMIT 0,10
```

And get a blank issue. Please, help make the right request to select 10 random users from the first table, with the exception of the users viewed by the teacher in the second table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LEFT JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html) is what you need. It will return all rows from LHS table that is not present in RHS table.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
LEFT JOIN teacherlook
ON users.id = teacherlook.userid 
   AND teacherlook.teachid = $teacherid
   AND users.age > 18
WHERE teacherlook.id IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Please accept my answer that will help someone with similar problem in future :)